# Prove that $x < y$ holds iff $\exists! p > 0$ such that $x + p = y$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How to prove, by real numbers axioms, that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ relation $x < y $ holds if and only if there exists unique $p > 0$ such that $x + p = y$?

I think this is powerful because it connects relation $"\leq"$ and $"="$ on the set of real numbers in the simillar way distributive property connects addition and multiplication.

Axiomatization we use in class:
(A1 - A8). $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ are both Abelian groups. (A9). Distributive property holds. (A10). There exist relation $"\leq"$ for which the following is true:
$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ is $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$. (A11) $x \leq, y \leq x \rightarrow x = y$, (A13) transitivity holds, (A14) $\forall x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ is $x + z \leq y + z$, (A15) $0 \leq x, 0 \leq y \rightarrow 0 \leq xy$ and finally we include (A15), that is, Completeness axiom.

Of course, we can write (by definition) $x \leq y$ as $y \geq x$.

And also how by this we define $"<"$?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean here. How are you defining the order $<$? And what does it mean for $p > 0$ to use the same symbol? Without knowing how we define these things, there's not much sense in proving stuff about them.

Comment: I can list axioms of $\mathbb{R}$ we use in class.

Comment: That seems helpful, along with how you define $<$.

Comment: Suppose $x < y$, then $0 < y - x = k$ satisfies $x + k = y$. Suppose $x + k = y$ for a positive $k$ then $0 < k = y-x$ so $x < y$.

Comment: @Zanzag, I think that's it. Please write this as an answer so I can rate it with green +1. :)

Comment: That solution is perfectly correct, but for it to actually make sense in your axiomatisation we first need to define $<$ at all, which the axioms doesn't do as listed---presumably this is something like $x < y$ if and only if $x \leq y$ and $x \neq y$ (or maybe $x \leq y$ and $y \not\leq x$). In this case you can *then* use the axioms about $\leq$ to do the above manipulations.

Comment: @prets, let's say we define it exactly as you wrote. Does this proof works then?

Comment: Yep, that works, but we'd also want to keep track of the "not equal" part (since we only have the axioms about adding things to inequalities for $\leq$, not $<$). Though of course you can instead first *prove* the same properties for $<$, and then Zanzag's argument works as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x < y$ then $0 < y-x = k$ satisfies $x+k=y$.
Suppose there exist $k > 0$ such that $x + k = y$ then $0 < k = y-x$ so $x <y$